# How to hide toolbar in start destination

Tags: android

I tried to hide the toolbar in start fragment, but the `View.GONE` not work when I explicitly set the toolbar in navigationUI.

```
// mainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

        toolbar = binding.toolbar
        // setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.secondFragment, R.id.thirdFragment), drawerLayout
        )

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.startFragment -> {
                    toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
            this, navController, appBarConfiguration
        )
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}

// activity_main.xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you try `binding.toolbar.hide()`

Comment: You're using `setupActionBarWithNavController`, but you've commented out the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` line. Are you using the ActionBar or not?

Comment: When try to setSupportActionBar in mainActivity, it report a `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead` error.

Comment: It happens because: "Caution: If you pass a Toolbar as the argument to setSupportActionBar(), the ActionBar assumes complete ownership of that Toolbar and you must not use any Toolbar APIs after that call. You can use the support for the ActionBar to connect the ActionBar to NavController." (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#support_app_bar_variations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
  toolbar = binding.toolbar
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar) // uncomment this line

  // ....

  navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.startFragment -> {
                supportActionBar?.hide() // to hide
            }else{
                supportActionBar?.show() // to show
            }
        }
  }
```

**OR**

You can hide `toolbar` from your `fragment` like below.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
}
```

And don't forget to call `show()` inside the `onStop()` in the same `fragment' to show the`toolbar`to other`fragment`or`activity`.

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add my own toolbar in activity_main.xml, and replace the the default style of theme with NoActionBar.

```
// in activity_main.xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

// in style.xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
</style>
```