# Android navigation component. Show full-screen dialog with morphing navigation icon from arrow to cross

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I created project from sample "Navigation drawer activity". Navigation icon works fine for top level and other destination. Navigation icon morphs from "hamburger" to "arrow" and back.

[image]

#### Issue

Ok. Now I need to implement full-screen dialog as it [recommended](https://material.io/components/dialogs#full-screen-dialog) for dialogs with keyboard input.

[image]

I created dialog fragment destination according [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-create-destinations#create-dialog):
**ProductCountChangeFragment.kt**

```kotlin
internal class ProductCountChangeFragment : DialogFragment(R.layout.product_count_change_fragment) {
    //...
}
```

**navigation.xml**

```xml
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/product_count_change_dialog_fragment"
    android:name="my.package.ProductCountChangeFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/product_count_change_fragment" />
```

It starts as regular dialog (not full-screen). I believe, navigation component supports material design recommendations, but I'm missing a tiny detail how to enable required behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can hide/show toolbar when fragment `attach()` and show in `detach()`

```kotlin
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    (activity as? MainActivity)?.run {
        goneBottomNavigation()
        setStatusBarColor(R.color.C_E6EBEF)    
    }   
}
```

2. this : same issue with you with navigation component : [How to hide toolbar in start destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380539/how-to-hide-toolbar-in-start-destination).

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. This example can't make navigation button morph from arrow to cross

Comment: If It didn't solve, you can use: add fragment. FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit()

Comment: Hmm. I need to write and support it on my own. I'm searching for solution from Navigation Component